# Can we split a string that has one of its delimeters in Android

Tags: android, stringtokenizer

I have a string like `1264$LP@$JOHN TAYLOR VS NJ Traffic$LP@$0$LP@$`. I want to split this string with `$LP@$` as a delimiter but this contains `L` (in TAYLOR) so while it should return

```
1264
JOHN TAYLOR VS NJ Traffic
0
```

it is giving like

```
1264
JOHN TAY
OR VS NJ Traffic
0
```

Could anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $ symbol is special character in regular expression. You need to escape it using '\'.

```
String input = "1264$LP@$JOHN TAYLOR VS NJ Traffic$LP@$0$LP@$";
String []pieces = input.split("\\$LP\\@\\$");

for(int i=0;i < pieces.length;i++)
  System.out.println(pieces[i]);
```

Output is
1264
JOHN TAYLOR VS NJ Traffic
0

Comment: thanks for the reply.great!! it works for me.can you please tell me why we are using \\ in front of each character

Comment: you need to escape $ with \ in regex then it will come as \$, you need to escape \ in Java String, then it come \\$

Comment: can you please tell me what is regex

Comment: A regular expression describes a search pattern. please go through http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/